# How king Janaka attained perfection through karma-yoga?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, janaka

> कर्मणैव हि संसिद्धिमास्थिता जनकादय: |
>
> लोकसंग्रहमेवापि सम्पश्यन्कर्तुमर्हसि ||  Shlok 20, Chapter 3, Bhagvat Geeta.

Lord Krishna had given an example of king Janaka for how to attain a perfection through karma-yoga. How King Janaka achieved **perfection(Purnata)** through karma-yoga?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya, Note that, Swami Gambhirananda, translate it as "liberation" and not "perfection" for the [BG 3.20](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=20&etgb=1&choose=1). BTW, you want to know how "King Janaka" in particular went through Karma Yoga Or how to achieve perfection through Karma Yoga, "in general".

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking whether karma yoga leads to salvation ? Krishna says it does.

Comment: @ram He asks it how it does?? Probably how Janaka practiced can answer this question.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, is he asking how Janaka did Karma Yoga ? Krishna gives the instruction for what Karma Yoga is - 'do dharma and don't wait for its fruits'. Janaka just followed the instruction. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

The detail story of Janaka attaining perfection in karma yoga and then liberation is present in the earlier chapters of [Upasama Kanda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118247.html) of Yoga Vasista.

Janaka, king of Videha, heard the songs of Siddhas in garden and then started vicharana based on the songs of the siddhas. He concluded as a part of vicharana that nishkama karma is a best way to perform karma and followed the same. As a consequence of that Janaka achieved liberation.

> Just as the effulgent sun in the Ākāśa causes days, etc., to happen
> without any volition or desire on their part, so also **Janaka
> contemplated upon performing, without any longing, all actions of his
> life which crop up spontaneously every day**. So never for a moment
> ruminating upon the past or future, productive as they are of evil, he
> began at once to transact his present actions with a full heart. **Only
> through the Ātmic enquiry created by the words of the Siddhas, did
> Janaka attain quiescence of mind and Ātma-jñāna**.
>
> [[The Story Of King Janaka, Upaṣānti-prakaraṇa (chapter 5), Laghu-yoga-vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/laghu-yoga-vasistha/d/doc209669.html)